# Stop rotation of image when it is on 0 or 180 degree

Tags: java, android, matrix

I am rotating the image by implementing the `onTouchListener` on `image-view`. Everything works fine but I want to stop the rotation of image when it reaches 0 degrees or 180 degrees (Horizontal center).

Here is the sample code I am using to rotate the image

```
     ImageView view = (ImageView) v;                                                                
       if (mode == ZOOM)
            {
            float newDist = spacing(event);
                if (newDist > 5f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float tScale = newDist / oldDist;
                    matrix.postScale(tScale, tScale, mid.x, mid.y);
                }
                //Rotate the image
                if (lastEvent != null) {
                    newRot = rotation(event);
                    float r = newRot - d;
                    matrix.postRotate(r, view.getMeasuredWidth() / 2,
                            view.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);

                }                                                                                    
             }

                private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
                    double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
                    double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
                    double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
                    return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
                }
```

This code is rotating the image but I want to indicate the user that your image is aligned at `center_horizontal`.

Thanks for any help.